# C++ console reading uncertain number of inputs and put them in an Array?

Tags: c++, arrays

1. Assume the following numbers are inputed in VC++ Console(separate with a **space**). N maybe 10, 20 or 100, it is uncertain.

   `1 2 3 4 ... N [Enter]`
2. The number of inputs is uncertain, maybe 10, or 20. After I press the **Enter** key, how put these numbers into an Array?

   `array[0]=1; array[1]=2; ...`

How to implement that with C++ code?

**(The number of inputs is uncertain!)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *PeterT* pointed out, If you don't know the size of the array ahead of time, you'll have to use *dynamic memory allocation*. Luckily, the *STL* has a container that does it for you.

You can use `std::vector` for that job.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::string nums; // the numbers in the format "1 2 3 4 10 -20"
    std::getline(std::cin,nums);

    std::stringstream stream(nums);
    int n;
    std::vector<int> vec;
    while(stream >> n) {
        vec.push_back(n);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(code is based on *Abdulla Al Sun*'s answer.)

This is an O(n) (linear complexity) solution.

If you want to convert it in to an actual array, you can do:

```
int array[vec.size()];
std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), array);
```

---

Another approach is to figure out how many elements the user inputted by storing his input in a string, and counting the tokens.

Then you know how big of an array you need.

```
unsigned int getSize(std::string s) {
    unsigned int size = 0;
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    int in;
    while (ss >> in)
        ++size;
    return size;
}

int main() {
    std::string nums; // the numbers in the format "1 2 3 4 10 -20"
    std::getline(std::cin,nums);
    const unsigned int size = getSize(nums);
    int array[size];
    std::stringstream stream(nums);
    int n;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; stream >> n && i < size; ++i) {
        array[i] = n;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is an O(2n) (linear complexity) solution.

---

My code assumes that the compiler allows variable array size. If it doesn't, use:

```
int* array = new int[size];
...
delete[] array;
```

To utilize RAII, wrap it in a struct like so:

```
struct DynArr {
    int* data;
    unsigned int size;
    DynArr(const unsigned int size) :
        size(size) {
        data = new int[size];
    }
    ~DynArr() {
        delete[] data;
    }
};
```

Comment: You can also use ´vector::data´ and ´memcpy´

Comment: @user4581301 or use `std::copy`

Comment: Yes, that would be better. Falling back on my C again.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int array[1000]; // your heighest input range
vector<int> numbers;

int main() {
    string nums; // the numbers in the format "1 2 3 4 10 -20"
    getline(cin,nums);

    stringstream stream(nums);
    int i = 0;
    int n;
    while(stream >> n){
        array[i++] = n;
        numbers.push_back(n);
    }
    // The number of integers in array is i. You can do anything with this number.
    // numbers contains the input numbers.
    return 0;
}
```

I have added `vector` after getting *PeterT*'s idea. You can add vector for not setting the static size of array.

Try this code. The header of stringstream is `sstream`. I have compiled in in codeblocks, I think this will work on VC++ compiler too.

Comment: But the Array **largest size** is 1000, if I do not want to limit the array size?

Comment: @kevin4z , Set the maximum approximate size. Or you can use Dynamic memory allocation following the link http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/

Comment: You can modify the code. But the basic is code I have implemented here

Comment: @kevin4z , You can maximize it. If this helps you, please accept the answer so that I can understand this helped you.

Comment: Thank you! But I'm a beginner and do not quite understand how to use `Dynamic memory allocation`...

Comment: @kevin4z you can just use `std::vector<int> numbers;` (after including the vector header) and do `numbers.push_back(n);` to add new elements. Also don't just accept the answer because someone tells you to, you know when your question is answered not somebody else.

Comment: @PeterT Yes,Thank you!

Comment: @AbdullaAlSun I have upvoted for your answer , but I want to get a more prefect answer .

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to steal Abdulla's code and make a couple slight modifications.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring.h> // for memcpy

//using namespace std; frowned on. polutes global namespace
//the highest input range is undefined, so this isn't safe
//int array[1000]; // your heighest input range

int main() {
    int max=10;
    int * array = new int[max];// allow resizing of array by dynamically allocating

    std::string nums; // the numbers in the format "1 2 3 4 10 -20"
    std::getline(std::cin,nums);

    std::stringstream stream(nums);
    int i = 0;
    while(stream){
        if (i==max)
        {
            int * temp = new int[max*2];// note statistical analysis has found 
                                        //1.5 is generally a better multiplier
            memcpy(temp, array, max*sizeof(array[0])); 
            // note do not use memcpy for copying complex data. It is too stupid.
            delete array; // release memory of old array
            array = temp; // replace old array with new array
            max*=2;
        }
        int n;
        stream>>n;
        array[i++] = n;
    }
    // The number of integers in array is i. You can do anything with this number.
    delete array; // all done. clean up.
    return 0;
}
```

The really smart way is to use a `std::vector`. Odds are really good that this is going to be frowned on by the marker, so make your own resizable array class. With a class you can easily take advantage of [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) and automate the clean-up so it's exception safe.

Comment: I'd recommend to avoid making your own comtainer(s)

Comment: @IvanRubinson most definitely. But all too often the library's containers are disallowed by instructors for reasons I don't quite agree with, or at least not as early as curriculums seem to prefer.